# When creating a package what is the correct location for "library" files sourced by bash scripts?

Tags: bash, arch-linux, fhs

I have a "library" file (containing general functions) I `source` in many different bash scripts. What's the correct filesystem [location](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html) to system-wide "install" this file in?

`/usr/lib/myBashlib/file.bash` ?

I don't want to place it below `/opt`, but properly install it by making a package for my distro.

EDIT: My distro specifies, that ["Packages should never be installed to /usr/local/"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_package_guidelines#Package_etiquette) (EDIT2:) and also "Avoid using /usr/libexec/ for anything".

EDIT3: I wonder, if the best way would be, to just define an environment variable (e.g. `MYBASHLIBPATH`) ... This would at least allow users of scripts that include this lib to install it locally instead of globally and then just set this variable to the path they installed it in ...

Answer (score 2):

FHS does **not** specify the location for *"library" files sourced by bash scripts* but the the desired locations could be `/usr/libexec/packagename` or `/usr/lib/packagename/`.

Locations with e.g. Bash scripts I've found on Fedora 36:

```
/usr/lib/dracut/
/usr/lib/rpm/
/usr/lib/systemd/
/usr/lib/virtualbox/

/usr/libexec/grub2/
/usr/libexec/mc/
/usr/libexec/selinux/
/usr/libexec/smartmontools/
/usr/libexec/thunar-archive-plugin/
```

And many others.

Comment: I just want to say I'm sorry: I didn't realize that you made location into a link.

Comment: Finally. It's OK. Have a good day :-)

Comment: Have a good day, too :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is standard place for "library" scripts. But you may find `/usr/local` tree convenient, for example `/usr/local/scripts`.